# post request ajax wsgi-python not working

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, wsgi

I am trying to get all the rows of a table for which checkbox is checked and keeping it in data1 array and sending the post request to python function.

```
<script>
var data1 = new Array();

$("input[type='checkbox'] :checked").each(function(){
        data1 = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function (){
          return $(this).text().trim();
          }).get();

    });

$.ajax({
  url : "check_myws_params",
  type :"POST",
  data : {the_post : data1}
});

</script>



def check_myws_params(environ,start_response):
   request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
   request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)

   d = parse_qs(request_body)
   data=d.get('the_post')
   print data //returns None.how to get the returned data1 from ajax.
```

Is there a missing part in generating payload in ajax?

Comment: Look at `request_body`?

Comment: it does not show "the_post" in the request body. I don't see a reason why? I am missing out on something.

Comment: What you do in situations like this, is either start from a minimal working code and add pieces to see which is failing, or vice versa.